# Kalman filter for heading estimation provides oscillating output

Tags: python, kalman-filter, sensor-fusion

I am designing a Kalman filter for heading estimation in 2D using magnetic compass, gyroscope and wheel encoder. The system state is
$ X = [h, w] $ and the measurements are $Z = [h_{mag}, g_z,d_h]$, where $h_{mag}$ is the heading computed with the compass, $g_z$ is the angular velocity measured with the gyroscope on the z axis and $d_h$ is the angle variation computed using the odometry equation:

$$
d_{left} = vl*dt 
$$
$$      
d_{right} = vr*dt 
$$
$$
d_h = (dleft - dright) / (wheel\_distance)  
$$

The state matrix is
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}1&dt\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$

The measurement matrix is
$$
H = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\\0&dt\end{bmatrix}
$$

My current implementation is as follows. Please note that my magnetometer is mounted with the X-axis onward and I'm using a reference system with 0° = north and clockwise increments from 0 to 359.

```
import numpy as np
PI = np.pi

class HeadingKF(object):
    '''
    State: [h, w]
    heading, angular speed
    Sensors: mag x y, gyr z, enc vl vr
    '''
    def __init__(self, h_deg, w_deg):
        self.wheel_distance = 1

        h = h_deg*PI/180
        w = w_deg*PI/180

        # State variables
        self.X = np.array([h, w])
        self.state_dim = len(self.X)
        self.A = np.eye(self.state_dim) # 2x2

        # Initial covariance
        self.P = np.eye(self.state_dim)  

        # Process noise
        self.Q = np.eye(self.state_dim)*0.1

        # Measurement noise
        self.R = np.eye(3) * 0.1

        # Measurement matrix (n sensors x state dim)
        # mag x and mag y are treated as one sensor (arctan output)
        # encoder values are treated as one sensor (odometry output)
        self.H = np.zeros((3, self.state_dim)) # mag h, gz, enc dh

    def update(self, mx, my, gz_deg, vl, vr, dt):

        # Prediction    
        
        # h = h0 + w dt
        self.A[0, 1] = dt

        self.X = np.dot(self.A, self.X)
        self.P = np.dot(np.dot(self.A, self.P), self.A.T) + self.Q

        # Update

        # mag measurement
        tmp = np.arctan2(mx, my) # measured h
        if mx >= 0 and my >= 0:
            tmp = 2*PI - tmp
        elif mx >= 0 and my < 0:
            tmp = -tmp
        elif mx < 0 and my < 0:
            tmp = -tmp
        elif mx < 0 and my >= 0:
            tmp = 2*PI - tmp
        tmp += PI/2
        
        # wrap
        tmp = wrap(tmp) # will go from 0 to 2pi
        mag_h = tmp     

        # gyr measurement
        gz = gz_deg*PI/180

        # enc measurement
        dleft = vl*dt 
        dright = vr*dt 
        dangle = (dleft - dright) / (2*self.wheel_distance) 

    
        # build H

        # mag_h = h 
        self.H[0,0] = 1

        # gz = w
        self.H[1, 1] = 1

        # d_angle = w*dt ??
        self.H[2, 1] = dt

        K = np.dot(np.dot(self.P, self.H.T), 
                       np.linalg.inv(np.dot(np.dot(self.H, self.P), 
                                            self.H.T) + self.R))
        

        Z = np.array([mag_h, gz, dangle])
        innovation = Z - np.dot(self.H, self.X)

        # innovation[0] must be wrapped from -180 to 180
        innovation[0] = (innovation[0] + PI) % 2*PI - PI    
        
        
        self.X = self.X + np.dot(K, innovation)
        self.X[0] = wrap(self.X[0])
        self.P = np.dot((np.eye(self.state_dim) - np.dot(K, self.H)), self.P)


        return self.X
```

As the image below shows, I have a very high oscillation in my output, despite the gyroscope and magnetometer providing a very similar heading computation on their own.

Is this problem related to the tuning of the noise matrices, or are there errors in my matrices and equations?
[image]